# MVC Controller routing, change the name of controller in url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I've got controller named `IHateYou`, and got loads of views inside that I can access through typing `...\IHateYou\User1`. I need to change the name of controller to `Users` in url, but the rest stays the same, so the users can still enter it through `...\Users\User1`. I've tried adding route, but I could still access it by the prior way.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add a constraints to your default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "IHateYou", action = "Index", id =UrlParameter.Optional },
constraints: new{ controller= "[^IHateYou]" });
```

default route alway match controller/action/id

Comment: I still can access it through `IHateYou`. There is an error when I try to access that resource ("`user`)

Comment: you need add a route Users/.... to controller IHateYou.add it before default route,and add constraints to default route,let it not match IHateYou/...